# handle reply from message box c#

Tags: c#, wpf

how can I handle message box reply example if the user click on yes do something if the user click on NO do another thing ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Example (slightly modified) from [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/411ze57x.aspx):

```
const string message =
    "Are you sure that you would like to close the form?";
const string caption = "Form Closing";
var result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption,
                             MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                             MessageBoxIcon.Question);

// If the no button was pressed ...
if (result == DialogResult.No)
{
    //Do something for No
} 
else if (result == DialogResult.Yes) 
{
    //Do something else for Yes
}
```

**Addendum**: In the event that you're still on .NET 2.0 and don't have access to the `var` keyword, declare `result` as a `DialogResult`. I.e:

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(...);
```

---

Missed the fact that this was tagged with WPF, so if you're using that then you'd be using the slightly (but not too much) different [System.Windows.MessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602949.aspx) class instead of System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox. The interaction is largely the same, but also uses the [MessageBoxResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messageboxresult.aspx) enum instead of DialogResult, the [MessageBoxImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messageboximage.aspx) enum instead of MessageBoxIcon, and the [MessageBoxButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.messageboxbutton.aspx) enum instead of MessageBoxButtons (plural). You should be able to do something like this:

```
const string message =
        "Are you sure that you would like to close the form?";
const string caption = "Form Closing";
MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show(message, caption,
                                 MessageBoxButton.YesNo,
                                 MessageBoxImage.Question);

if (result == MessageBoxResult.No)
{
    // Do something for No
}
else if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
{
    // Do something else for Yes
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Since the tag states WPF and **NOT WinForms**, you will need to do something like this for a MessageBox:

```
MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Foo Bar?", "Confirmation", MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel);
if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
{
    // yeah yeah yeah stuff
}
else if (result == MessageBoxResult.No)
{
    // no no no stuff
}
else
{
    // forget about it
}
```

In addition the dialogs are dealt with differently in WPF as well, note the absence of `DialogResult`:

```
SomeDialog dialog = new SomeDialog();
dialog.ShowDialog();

if (dialog.DialogResult.HasValue && dialog.DialogResult.Value)
     MessageBox.Show("Clicked ok");
else
     MessageBox.Show("Clicked cancel");
```

Answer (score 3):

You should try using [google](http://tinyurl.com/24s5znp) or [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com) (the links are clickable).

Anyways, you should check the value of the messageboxresult returned by the show method.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598674.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The best for me is

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to close the window ?", "Question", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Warning) == MessageBoxResult.No)
        {
            //do NO stuff
        }
        else
        {
            //do YES stuff
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Some Text", "Title", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);

if(result == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

```
DialogResult userSelection = MessageBox.Show("Some question","Question",MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,MessageBoxIcon.Question);

// Do something with userSelection
```

Answer (score 0):

childwindow's in WPF are asynchronous actions. You have to handle the Close event, and inside your close event then you can perform your logic.